# How to dynamically replace content in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I want to replace all `{baseurl}` keywords to proper url in TinyMCE editor. How can i do that?

For example if user will add HTML in editor `<img src="{baseurl}/image.jpg" />` i want to see this image in TinyMCE editor - so this will be replaced to `<img src="http://mydomain.com
/image.jpg" />`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here is the code that will replace your editor content. But you will need to do this action at the correct time.

```
var editor = tinymce.get('my_editor_id'); // use your own editor id here - equals the id of your textarea
var content = editor.getContent();
content = content.replace(/{\$baseurl}/g, 'http://mydomain.com');
editor.setContent(content);
```

Comment: glad to have been able to help :)

Comment: ````var editor = tinyMCE.get('my_editor_id');```` also works.

Comment: @Thariama, is it possible to select 1 value inside a data attribute out of multiple values present?

For eg: `<div data-arr="attr1 attr2 attr3">content</div>` and I want to replace only the `attr2` with `attr4` inside the `data-arr` attribute of all `div` tags, where I don't know the exact position of `attr2` inside `data-arr` attribute (i.e. it may be in the start, or middle, or end)

I loop through each element that matches one of the present attribute using the `~=` CSS selector in JQuery, but my question is, how would I reflect those changes in the TinyMCE editor?

Comment: @ParasShah: you should store each of your values in an own data-attribute to avoid such hassle

Answer (score 2):

With this solution I was able to modify the content on-the-fly, without replacing the content as whole:

```
tinymce.init({
   setup: (editor)=>{
      editor.on('init', ()=>{
         $(editor.contentDocument).find('a').prop('title', 'my new title');
      });
   }
});
```

Maybe it helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

I used a very simple code working good with me

```
tinymce.get("page-content").setContent(''); // 'page-content' as the textarea id
tinymce.get("page-content").execCommand('mceInsertContent', !1, 'New content data');
```